# php foreach counting new lines (\n)

Tags: php, string, foreach

If I have a piece of code that works like this:

```
$i = 0;
$names = explode(",", $userInput);
foreach($names as $name) {
    $i++;
}
```

It works perfectly, provided the user has placed a comma after each name entered into the html textarea this comes from. But I want to make it more user friendly and change it so that each name can be entered on a new line and it'll count how many lines the user has entered to determine the number of names entered into the field. So I tried:

```
$i = 0;
$names = explode("\n", $userInput);
foreach($names as $name) {
    $i++;
}
```

But this just gives me "1" as a result, regardless the number of new lines in the textarea. How do I make my explode count new lines instead of basing the count on something specifically entered into the text string?

**EDIT** Thanks to the people who answered, I don't believe there were any wrong answers as such, just one that suited my original code better than the others, and functioned. I ended up adopting this and modifying it so that numerous blank line returns did not result in artificially inflating the $userInput count. Here is what I am now using:

```
    if(($userInput) != NULL) {
        $i = 0;
        $names = explode(PHP_EOL, trim($userInput));
        foreach($names as $name) {
            $i++;
        }
    }
```

It trims the empty space from the $userInput so that the remainder of the function is performed on only valid line content. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the PHP end of line constant PHP_EOL

```
$names = explode(PHP_EOL, $userInput);
```

Comment: I do not understand why your answer was downvoted. It was the best fit of them all to my original code and was the easiest to switch to without fiddling. I've slightly modified your answer, please check my edit in the main question.

Answer (score 3):

Don't make it complicated, you don't have to explode it into an array, just use this:

(Just count the new line character ([`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)) in your string with [`substr_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php))

```
echo substr_count($userInput, PHP_EOL);
```

Comment: @Ghost It will be hard to tell why I got a down vote, *people are just strange animals* :) (But I think Sherlock Holmes will whisper me the answer in the hear)

Comment: lol :D you'll rather get a long explanation for that, another one of those occasional rage downvoter i guess

Answer (score 0):

A blank string as input:

```
var_dump(explode("\n", ''));
```

gives this as a result from a call to explode():

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }
```

so you could use a ternary statement:

```
$names = $userInput == '' ? array() : explode("\n", $userInput);
```

Comment: Thanks Mex but yeah, a bit overkill for the result required.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the explode function with preg_split to explode the user string with a regex

```
$users = preg_split('/[\n\r]+/', $original);
```

That's the idea, but I'm not on the computer so I can't test my code.
That regex would split the string if it founds one or more line breaks.

Comment: Thanks Alexys, I might have given this a try perhaps if it had been shown in relationship to my existing code. I see what you're getting at but the answer I accepted was a bit more cleaner and simpler. :)